# Can't find disk usage in one directory

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement

Similar questions are asked frequently but no suggested answers solved my issue. I have some disk space usage that I can't find as well.

In df

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      144183992 136857180      2652 100% /
udev             2013316         4   2013312   1% /dev
tmpfs             808848       876    807972   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2022116        76   2022040   1% /run/shm
overflow            1024         0      1024   0% /tmp
```

I checked the inodes, I checked lsof for +L1 or deleted files, I rebooted, I checked for files hidden behind mounts but none of them were the issue. It grows periodically and I'm running out of things to delete to feed the beast. It's all in the home directory of the only user I have.

In du in ~

```
du -h --max-depth=1
192K    ./.nv
2.1M    ./.gconf
12K ./Pictures
1.6M    ./.launchpadlib
12K ./Public
24K ./.TemporaryItems
8.9M    ./.cache
12K ./Network Trash Folder
28K ./.vnc
11M ./.AppleDB
48K ./.subversion
1.9G    ./.xbmc
8.0K    ./.AppleDesktop
12K ./.dbus
81M ./.mozilla
12K ./Music
160K    ./.gnome2
44K ./Downloads
692K    ./.zsh
236K    ./.AppleDouble
64K ./.pulse
4.0K    ./.gvfs
1.4M    ./.adobe
44K ./.pki
44K ./.compiz-1
168K    ./.config
1.4M    ./.thumbnails
12K ./Templates
912K    ./.gstreamer-0.10
8.0K    ./.emacs.d
92K ./Desktop
1.3M    ./.local
12K ./Ubuntu One
12K ./Documents
296K    ./.fontconfig
12K ./.qt
12K ./.gnome2_private
20K ./.ssh
20K ./.mission-control
12K ./Videos
12K ./Temporary Items
640K    ./.macromedia
124G    .
```

I can't find a way to figure out how it got to that 124G in that directory. There are no mount points in home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output from `du` is complete, then it seems that there are some large files directly in the home directory (not in any subdirectory). I would try running something like this in your home:

```
du -ms  * .* --exclude ".." --exclude "."| sort -n
```

to obtain the list including files directly in ~, sorted by size.

Comment: omg, I'm such a n00b. You're right, it was a file

Comment: for future references, probably shouldn't put -h with du since 2K > 1G

Comment: yes -h is of course stupid. I originally wanted to write -m. Thank you